# Restoration of purchases if they were made on another platform

Tags: flutter, dart

I am interested in this question - How to restore purchases if made on another platform? I use [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase) to implement in app purchases

For example, a user makes a subscription on Android, after which he decides to continue working on iOS. And then the question arises - Is it possible using methods getAvailablePurchases() or getPurchaseHistory() to restore past purchases from another platform? Or maybe there are other ways to restore the correct purchases?

Please tell me how do you deal with this problem?

Comment: Can't you manage purchases on your Database? Linking the user account with purchases instead of trying to check with with platforms?

Comment: I use firebase and in principle I can save purchase data. And the only way to restore subscriptions, as it seems to me in this case, is to look at the subscription date and add plus one month or plus one year to this date, but I think this is not a very good way to restore

Comment: Therefore, I thought that a better way to restore using methods from the library, but these methods will probably show only purchases for a specific platform